# how to create variable column from my table SAS 4GL - RETAIN?

Tags: sas, retain, 4gl

I have dataset in the followin format. The first 5 variables are already exist. I need to create the "NEED_TO".

It means that after row with '1' on column MTH_SATTL and when date on START column is older then date on DATA column then fill in 1 till to the next GROUP nad GR_ROZL.

I tried use RETAIN statement, but i think i make something wrong in syntax

```
Data        Start       Group   GR_ROZL MTH_SATTL   Need_to
01OCT2019   .           G11     2       0           0
01NOV2019   .           G11     2       0           0
01DEC2019   .           G11     2       0           0
01JAN2020   01JAN2020   G11     2       0           0
01FEB2020   01JAN2020   G11     2       1           1
01MAR2020   01JAN2020   G11     2       0           1
01APR2020   01JAN2020   G11     2       0           1
01OCT2019   .           G11     3       0           0
01NOV2019   .           G11     3       0           0
01DEC2019   .           G11     3       0           0
01JAN2020   01JAN2020   G11     3       0           0
01FEB2020   01JAN2020   G11     3       0           0
01MAR2020   01JAN2020   G11     3       1           1
01APR2020   01JAN2020   G11     3       0           1
01OCT2019   .           G12W    2       0           0
01NOV2019   .           G12W    2       0           0
01DEC2019   .           G12W    2       0           0
01JAN2020   01JAN2020   G12W    2       0           0
01FEB2020   01JAN2020   G12W    2       1           1
01MAR2020   01JAN2020   G12W    2       0           1
01APR2020   01JAN2020   G12W    2       0           1
```

Comment: You are referring to a column called `start_podwyzka` in your code but you have a column called `start` in your sample data. Please provide this extra column or correct your code.

Comment: Also, you have `group` in your sample data but `GRUPA_TARYFOWA` in your code.

Comment: I deleted my code. It's wrong totally.

Comment: Please include what you've tried, even if it's wrong. The goal of this site is to help you fix it, not to write it for you..

Comment: i preper code:                                                                                      data want;
set have;

IF START ne '.' then 
 do;
by  GROUP GR_ROZL NOTSORTED;
 RETAIN NEED_TO 0;

 IF FIRST.GROUP THEN NEET_TO = 0;
 IF not NEED_TO AND START ge DATA THEN NEED_TO = 1;

 end;
else NEED_TO = MTH_SATTL;
run;

Comment: and then I receive in 4th row '1' on column NEED_TO. I should receive '0', '1' should have from 5th row to the next observation with 'n+1' on  GR_ROZL column

Comment: @ecart, please edit your question and add any updated information or further elucidation.  Placing more info in comments makes things hard to locate and follow.

Comment: Great, thnx for support and your advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule "fill in 1 till to the next GROUP and GR_ROZL" means you will want to have by processing.  If the `BY` groups are contiguous but not collated you will need the `NOTSORTED` option.  You will also need a `RETAIN`ed variable that gets reset at the start of a group and conditionally assigned according to your logic.

Example:

```
data want;
  set have;
  by group gr_rozl NOTSORTED;

  retain need_to 0;

  * reset at the start of group;
  if first.gr_rozl then need_to = 0;

  * assign need_to if it is unassigned and meets assignment criteria;
  * this ensures the assigned value is carried forward (via retain) until reset again;
  if not need_to and start < data then need_to = 1;

  * alternate way to assign using logic operator OR;
  * need_to = need_to OR (start < data);
run;
```

To set the `need_to` value on the **subsequent rows** after first occurrence of `start < data` you can use an additional retained variable as a logic flag.

Example:

```
data have; input
Date        Start       Group $   GR_ROZL MTH_SATTL; 
attrib date start informat=date9. format=date9.;datalines;
01OCT2019   .           G11     2       0          
01NOV2019   .           G11     2       0          
01DEC2019   .           G11     2       0          
01JAN2020   01JAN2020   G11     2       0          
01FEB2020   01JAN2020   G11     2       1          
01MAR2020   01JAN2020   G11     2       0          
01APR2020   01JAN2020   G11     2       0          
01OCT2019   .           G11     3       0          
01NOV2019   .           G11     3       0          
01DEC2019   .           G11     3       0          
01JAN2020   01JAN2020   G11     3       0          
01FEB2020   01JAN2020   G11     3       0          
01MAR2020   01JAN2020   G11     3       1          
01APR2020   01JAN2020   G11     3       0          
01OCT2019   .           G12W    2       0          
01NOV2019   .           G12W    2       0          
01DEC2019   .           G12W    2       0          
01JAN2020   01JAN2020   G12W    2       0          
01FEB2020   01JAN2020   G12W    2       1          
01MAR2020   01JAN2020   G12W    2       0          
01APR2020   01JAN2020   G12W    2       0          
run;

data want;
  set have;
  by group gr_rozl NOTSORTED;

  retain need_to need_to_flag 0;

  * reset at the start of group;
  if first.gr_rozl then do; need_to = 0; need_to_flag = 0; end;

  * set retained value for fill in;
  if not need_to and need_to_flag then need_to = 1;

  * set flag for setting retained value on subsequent rows;
  if mth_sattl and not need_to_flag and start < date then need_to_flag = 1;

  drop need_to_flag;
run;
```

Comment: thank a lot for your fast answer, but I made mistake on describes. In your code I receive for exemples 4th row '1' on column NEED_TO. I should receive '0', '1' should have from  5th row.